# Comparing performance of query for year in date

Tags: mysql, datetime, database-performance, query-performance

How would the following three queries compare in terms of performance? I'm trying to get all records with year=2017:

Using `EXTRACT`:

```
SELECT count(*), completed_by_id FROM table 
WHERE EXTRACT(YEAR FROM completed_on)=2017 
GROUP BY completed_by_id
# Took 11.8s
```

Using `YEAR`:

```
SELECT count(*), completed_by_id FROM table 
WHERE YEAR(completed_on)=2017 
GROUP BY completed_by_id
# Took 5.15s
```

Using `LIKE 'YEAR%`'

```
SELECT count(*), completed_by_id FROM table 
WHERE completed_on LIKE '2017%' 
GROUP BY completed_by_id
# Took 6.61s
```

**Note**: In my own testing I found `YEAR()` to be the fastest, `LIKE` to be the second fastest, and `EXTRACT()` to be the slowest.

There are about 5M rows in the table and `completed_on` is `DATETIME` field that has been indexed.

Comment: You do have an index on `completed_on` field, right?

Comment: @PM77-1 yes that has an index.

Comment: How many records are we talking about?

Comment: @PM77-1 ~ 5 million

Comment: What column type is `completed_on` ?

Comment: This is a handy guide to SQL questions. Especially read the part about query performance. http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/271056/

Comment: @O.Jones thanks for the link -- I added some updates to the question with more details

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You haven't described your table or indexes so all advice about query performance is guesswork.

If your `completed_on` column is a `DATETIME`, `DATE`, or `TIMESTAMP` type *and* it is indexed, this query will radically outperform all the ones you have shown, and maintain its performance as your table grows.

```
SELECT count(*), completed_by_id
  FROM table 
 WHERE completed_on >= '2017-01-01'
   AND completed_on <  '2017-01-01' + INTERVAL 1 YEAR
 GROUP BY completed_by_id
```

Why? It can do a range scan on the index rather than a [nonsargable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sargable) function call on each row's value.

Notice the use of `>=` at the beginning of the date range and `<` at the end. We want to include all rows from the first moment of new years day 2017, up until *but not including* the first moment of new years day 2018. `BETWEEN` can't do this, because it uses `<=` rather than `<` at the end of its range.

If an index is in place, both `BETWEEN` and the syntax I have shown use a range scan, and perform about the same.

For best results speeding up this query use a compound index on `(completed_on, completed_by_id)`.

Comment: Will `BETWEEN` be exactly the same?

Comment: No, `BETWEEN` yields incorrect results. See my edit.

Comment: I meant *properly used* `BETWEEN` - have Dec 31st as its max.

Comment: @O.Jones the above query performed a tad better than using `YEAR()`. It gave about a 2% speedup.

Comment: What you suggest will work if the column is a `DATE` value. But it will require `BETWEEN '2017-01-01' AND `2017-12-31 23:59` if the column is a  `TIMESTAMP` or `DATETIME`.  And if the time has subsecond resolution even that won't be correct.

Comment: @David542 add the compound index I suggested if you need better perf.

Answer (score 0):

If you are storing completed_on as DATE or DATETIME you can use:

```
SELECT count(*) as cnt, LEFT(completed_on, 4) AS year
FROM table 
GROUP BY year
HAVING year=2017
```